# Runtime error 424 VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've had a some success creating a project script that throws up some dialogues to take information, place it on a worksheet (activex box) and then print.

My code runs fine when located in `Sheet1` object with the VB editor.  However, I want it to run on excel open, so I paste it into the `thisworkbook` object within `workbook_open()`, but nothing works.

Can anyone explain to me how I can get this script to run upon excel open, or cease to receive the 424 error when running it from `workbook_open()`?

The debugger doesn't like my `labelbatch` and `labelexpiry` objects (but only when in `thisworkbook`), but it works fine otherwise.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Activate

'Clears label fields prior to data entry
labelbatch.Caption = ""
LabelExpiry.Caption = ""


'Auto input of batch code into batch field using input text.
BatchNo = InputBox("Enter batch code", " ")
labelbatch.Caption = BatchNo

'Auto input of expiry date into expiry field using input text.
ExpiryDate = InputBox("Enter expiry date", " ")
LabelExpiry.Caption = ExpiryDate

'Show print dialog box
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

'Close without saving changes
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

  End Sub
```

Comment: Most of us do not have the Excel error codes memorized, so the error text would be helpful as well.

Comment: Apologies
Run-time error '424' Object required

Comment: what are Labelbatch and LabelExpiry and where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `labelbatch` and `labelExpiry` are objects on the worksheet, when the code is moved to ThisWorkbook VBA doesn't know where to look for those objects.  Use e.g.

```
thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").labelbatch
```

to refer to them.

When you use a method or property name without all its parents, VBA will either throw an error or will use a default depending on the context.  For example, for `Cells()`, `Range()` and the like, that default is `Application.ActiveSheet`.  That is generally risky: it's very hard to be sure what the active worksheet will be if you later change your code (or even if a user switches sheets while your code is running).  Better to specify which worksheet you want.

This does make references to objects longer, but you can always use `With...End With` to help readability and save typing.